# Why doesn't this Dojo 1.9/JS code work in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dojo

We are having a problem with a web application that uses Dojo 1.9.   The application works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10/11 but we are getting reports of a problem in IE 7.

**UNFORTUNATELY**, I have no way to test this directly because by corporate directive, IE 7 was removed from all developer machines.   So I am responsible for fixing a bug I have no way to duplicate.

Because of user feedback, all the buttons in the application were changed from type="submit" to type="button" and an onclick() handler was added to the buttons so that the form would be submitted **only** when the button was clicked but not when ENTER was pressed.   Here is the dojo/domReady! code that wires the buttons:

```
    //  Make the buttons submit the form ONLY on click (avoid keypress)
    query("button[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("    in button onclick handler");
        //  This actually submits the form based on the button that was clicked
        myapp.core.buttonClick("applicationInfo",this);
        console.log("    leaving button onclick handler");
    })
```

Here is the routine that actually submits the form (myapp.core.buttonClick):

```
    myapp.core.buttonClick = function(formName, buttonObject) {
        // Have to do this to transmit the data - the button info
        // won't be transmitted otherwise
        var formObject = document.forms[formName];
        var newField = document.createElement('input');
        newField.type = 'hidden';
        newField.name = buttonObject.name;
        newField.value = buttonObject.value;
        formObject.appendChild(newField);
        formObject.submit();
    }
```

Can anybody familiar with IE7 spot the problem in this code?   Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried a service such as BrowserStack? http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Yes, I have tried this in BrowserStack and verified that it fails, but the tools available on BrowserStack are not enough to allow me to identify WHERE it is failing.   It's a catch-22 - I can see it happen on Browserstack but not debug it, and I can debug it locally but not make the bug happen.

Comment: Sounds weird but how about changing the `console.log`s with alerts (on a staging environment so you don't push this live)?

Comment: Manual old-school debugging, eh?   It's worth a try....

Comment: As per the release notes Dojo 1.9x does not support IE7
[http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/it-s-a-bug-used-dojo-1-9-when-use-ie7-mode-to-view-dojo-tutorials-for-Dialogs-amp-ToolTips-it-displa8-td3997498.html](link1)
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/1.9.html
My 2 cents. It might be the problem with the dojo.on module not working on IE7, could you try the old dojo.connect module and see whether it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:   IE7 and Spring Web Flow are not compatible.

Long Answer:

Not only does [Dojo 1.9 not support IE 7](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/1.9.html), but IE7 turns out to be [very problematic with Spring Web Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461867/getting-spring-web-flow-to-work-with-ie-7-forms).   Because IE7 submits all buttons to the server, regardless of what button is clicked, it is a hassle to pass Web Flow events back to the server using IE7 and required a very ugly hack:

```
var formObject = document.forms[formName];
//  Rip out the buttons because IE7 sucks
for (i=0;i<formObject.length;i++) {
    if (formObject[i].tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        formObject[i].parentNode.removeChild(formObject[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
var newField = document.createElement('input');
newField.type = 'hidden';
newField.id=buttonObject.id;
newField.name = buttonObject.name;
if (buttonObject.attributes['value'] != null) {
    newField.value = buttonObject.attributes['value'].value;
} else {
    newField.value = buttonObject.value;
}
formObject.appendChild(newField);
formObject.submit();
```

This hack basically rips out all the button objects from the form, then adds back the **one button** that was actually clicked as a hidden field, and then submits the form.